# Swing components are too small

Tags: java, swing

So I have this code in my contructor, my class extends JFrame:

```
    super("myBucketList");

    i = new Item();


    //controls panel
    controls = new JPanel();

    itemField = new JTextField();
    itemField.addActionListener(new ListenAction());

    delField = new JTextField();
    delField.addActionListener(new ListenAction());

    listArea = new JTextArea();
    listArea.setEditable(false);

    controls.add(delField);
    controls.add(itemField);


    //txtareaPanel
    textareaPanel = new JPanel();

    listScroll = new JScrollPane();
    listScroll.setViewportView(listArea);

    textareaPanel.add(listScroll);


    //tab1 panel
    tab1 = new JPanel();
    tab1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    tab1.add(controls, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    tab1.add(textareaPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


    add(tab1);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500,200);
    setVisible(true);
```

Now if I run my application the components are really small, how to fix it?

Here is a screenshot of the situation/problem: http://snag.gy/yjbUl.jpg

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call the constructor with columns, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField%28int%29)

For example:

```
itemField = new JTextField(10); //Or the number of cols you want
```

Or call [`JTextField#setColumns()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#setColumns%28int%29)

```
itemField.setColumns(10); //Or the number of columns you want
```

For the `JTextArea` call this [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#JTextArea%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29) as follows:

```
listArea = new JTextArea("", 10, 10); //Text, rows, cols.
```

Or again use [`JTextArea#setRows()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setRows%28int%29) and [`JTextArea#setColumns()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#setColumns%28int%29) as follows:

```
listArea.setColumns(10);
listArea.setRows(10);
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jdk 8 then keep it but 
download the jre 9 and your widgets
etc will be of normal size. This solves the 
problem!